# how to Set variable in INFORMIX DB according to IF else condtion for a dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, informix

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE Table_info
(parIn CHAR(12), parIn2 CHAR(12), parIn3 CHAR(20),parIn4 CHAR(2))
RETURNING CHAR(12) AS paramenter1,CHAR(23) AS parameter2,CHAR(2) AS parameter3,CHAR(12) AS parameter4,CHAR(1) AS parameter5,INTEGER AS parameter6 ;
DEFINE paramenter1 CHAR(12);
DEFINE parameter2 CHAR(22);
DEFINE parameter3 CHAR(2);
DEFINE parameter4 CHAR(12);
DEFINE parameter5 CHAR(1);
DEFINE parameter6 INTEGER;
DEFINE cust_qry   CHAR(1024);
LET cust_qry = "select pt.paramenter1,pt.parameter2,pt.parameter3,pt.parameter4,pt.parameter5,pt.parameter6              from X pt, outer X ps   where pt.set_no = ps.set_no and   pt.paramenter1 = '" || parIn || "' ";

IF    parIn2 = '' THEN
LET cust_qry = cust_qry ;
ELSE
LET cust_qry = cust_qry || "and pt.parameter4 = '"|| parIn2 || "' " ;
END IF;
if parIn3 != '' then 
LET cust_qry = cust_qry ||"and pt.trd_blk_ref = '"|| parIn3 ||"' " ;    
END IF;
if ( parIn4 != '0') then 
LET cust_qry = cust_qry ||"and pt.parameter3 = '"|| parIn4 ||  "' " ;
END IF;

       PREPARE stmt_id FROM cust_qry;
   DECLARE cust_cur cursor FOR stmt_id;
   OPEN cust_cur; 
     WHILE (1 = 1)
     FETCH cust_cur INTO paramenter1, parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,parameter5,parameter6;
     if (sqlcode = 100 ) then exit; end if;
      RETURN paramenter1,parameter2,parameter3,parameter4,parameter5,parameter6 WITH RESUME ;
        end while;
```

I have cerated a store procedur in Informix DB .It has created successfully without any error .
and excutes without anyerror .
Only problem is it is not recongnizing IF else condition where i have added 
    LET cust_qry = cust_qry || "and pt.parameter4 = '"|| parIn2 || "' " ;

Please help me :(

I have no problem in compiling and excuting Store Procedure its just that even if i pass parameter 1 and parameter 2 to store procedure its not going into if condition where i have mentioned 
IF    parIn2 != '' THEN
LET cust_qry = cust_qry || "and pt.parameter4 = '"|| parIn2 || "' " ;

so that my query should be dynamix and resulted query should be as below 
as i have passes both parIn /parIn2

select pt.paramenter1,pt.parameter2,pt.parameter3,pt.parameter4,pt.parameter5,pt.parameter6  from X pt, outer X ps where pt.set_no = ps.set_no and   pt.paramenter1 = '" || parIn || "' and pt.parameter4 = '"|| parIn2 || "'" ;

But problem is its giving me query till only

select pt.paramenter1,pt.parameter2,pt.parameter3,pt.parameter4,pt.parameter5,pt.parameter6  from X pt, outer X ps where pt.set_no = ps.set_no and   pt.paramenter1 = '" || parIn || "'

its not considering parIn2 even when its not null .. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you could add the following 2 lines after the define to help in debugging the procedure.

> SET DEBUG FILE TO '/tmp/trace.log'; TRACE ON

please post trace.log

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your arguments are empty strings and not nulls or spaces etc?

Try rewriting that first `IF` statement:

```
IF parIn2 IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(parIn2) != '' THEN
    LET cust_qry = cust_qry || "and pt.parameter4 = '"|| parIn2 || "' " ;
END IF;
```